# linux kernel panic when transfer from usb luks encrypted disk

Tags: cryptsetup

I have this situation

A encrypted with luks usb3 disk

on this disk,a big backup of 1.7T

some files are over 140G

When I transfer the big file give me a kernel panic

I try to change the i/o with

```
nice -n 19 ionice -c 3 rsync...
```

but nothing

I switch from 4.10 kernel to 4.4 slackware kernel

but nothing..still panic

What can it be?A bug of hw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A kernel panic is usually a bug of kernel. Kernel should handle error of hardware and software gracefully.  There are few exceptions: memory errors cannot be easily recovered by kernels, but it doesn't seem the case.

But probably there is also some problem on the USB.  Try a newer kernel, which possibly have a better error message.

Comment: Probably is hw problem,because i tried on other machine(with usb3) and no panic.The problem start when i upgrade ram to 16G,the working machine had 4G